# SORTING A SQUARE MATRIX + OPTIMIZE SOURCE CODE

Tags: sorting, optimization, matrix, quicksort, gprof

I'm trying to optimize some source code, can anyone of you help me? In your opinion which is the best way to sort a matrix efficiently in ascending order? Compulsory the sorting must be inside a square matrix...

I think the following source code can be optimized:

```
# define TAM 100
int i,j,k;

    for (k=TAM-1; k>=0; k=k-1)
{

    for (j=m; j<TAM; j=j+1)
    {
        // instruction
    }

    for (i=k; i<TAM; i=i+1) 
    {
        // instruction
    }   

};
```

Comment: When you say "sort a square matrix" do you mean sort the rows by the value of a particular column? If so, you could use `qsort` or a merge sort, and an indirection array so you're not moving masses of data around. Regardless, I can't figure out what your code is trying to do. For example, what is `m`?